# How to get console log from axios promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-dom

This is driving me crazy. I cannot see the `response` object from my `axios POST` request.

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class SignUp extends Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: ''
  };

  handleNameChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleEmailChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      email: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handlePasswordChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      password: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {
      name,
      email,
      password
    } = this.state;
    const user = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: password
    };
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:7777/signup', {
        user
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return ( <
      form className = "form-signin"
      onSubmit = {
        this.handleSubmit
      } >
      <
      h2 className = "form-signin-heading" > Please sign up < /h2> <
      label htmlFor = "inputName"
      className = "sr-only" >
      Name <
      /label> <
      input type = "name"
      name = "name"
      onChange = {
        this.handleNameChange
      }
      id = "inputName"
      className = "form-control"
      placeholder = "Name"
      required /
      >
      <
      label htmlFor = "inputEmail"
      className = "sr-only" >
      Email address <
      /label> <
      input type = "email"
      name = "email"
      onChange = {
        this.handleEmailChange
      }
      id = "inputEmail"
      className = "form-control"
      placeholder = "Email address"
      required /
      >
      <
      label htmlFor = "inputPassword"
      className = "sr-only" >
      Password <
      /label> <
      input type = "password"
      name = "password"
      onChange = {
        this.handlePasswordChange
      }
      id = "inputPassword"
      className = "form-control"
      placeholder = "Password"
      required /
      >

      <
      button className = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
      type = "submit" >
      Sign up <
      /button> <
      /form>
    );
  }
}

export default SignUp;
```

Someone please tell me what I am missing. I am getting the server `console` messages. But I cannot see the message in my browser developer tools.

Here is my backend code.

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors({
  origin: "http://localhost:3019"
}));

app.post('/signin', function(req, res) {
  let useremail = req.body.email;
  let password = req.body.password;
  if (useremail && password) {
    console.log('success')
  } else {
    console.log('Failure');
  }
});

app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
  let userfullname = req.body.fullname;
  let useremail = req.body.email;
  let password = req.body.password;
  console.log(`
    Thank you ${userfullname} for signing up, 
    your login credentials are 
    login: ${useremail}
    password: ${password}  
  `)
});

app.listen(7777, function() {
  console.log("Started listening on port", 7777);
})
```

Comment: Did you see in network tab in  chrome devtools ? Did API got success headers ?

Comment: Looks about right. Seeing request in your network tab? no log showing at all for success or catch? Is page on same port `7777` as api endpoint?

Comment: No it just says pending

Comment: no response being returned from `app.post`. Add something like `res.json(req.body)`

Comment: how are you returning the response

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that your request handlers [return a response](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res), per request.

For instance, you could send a JSON response to signal to the client/browser that the request has been processed and completed by doing something like this:

```
app.post('/signin', function(req, res) {
  let useremail = req.body.email;
  let password = req.body.password;
  if (useremail && password) {
    console.log('success')
  } else {
    console.log('Failure');
  }

  /* 
  Add this: send a json response to client 
  */
  res.json({ message : 'sign in request completed' });
});

app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
  let userfullname = req.body.fullname;
  let useremail = req.body.email;
  let password = req.body.password;
  console.log(`
    Thank you ${userfullname} for signing up, 
    your login credentials are 
    login: ${useremail}
    password: ${password}  
  `)

  /* 
  Add this: send a json response to client 
  */
  res.json({ message : 'sign up request completed' });
});
```

In addition to [`json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json), the express framework's [Response interface](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) offers other response methods such as [`send()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) and [`end()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end) that may be better suited to your use case.

The key concept here is that an incoming request should have a corresponding response sent back to the client. This allows to the client to correctly respond to, and resume from, network requests sent to your sever.

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke `res.json('Success');` atleast to see any response. Right now the backend API code doesn't response on both the API's

So the modified code can look like

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors({
  origin: "http://localhost:3019"
}));

app.post('/signin', function(req, res) {
  let useremail = req.body.email;
  let password = req.body.password;
  if (useremail && password) {
    res.json({status:'Success'});
  } else {
    res.json({status:'Failed'});
  }
});

app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
  let userfullname = req.body.fullname;
  let useremail = req.body.email;
  let password = req.body.password;
  res.json({messahge:`
    Thank you ${userfullname} for signing up, 
    your login credentials are 
    login: ${useremail}
    password: ${password}  
  `})


});

app.listen(7777, function() {
  console.log("Started listening on port", 7777);
})
```